# Mapquest: This key is not authorized for this service

Tags: c#, .net, openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding, mapquest

I am trying to use [Geocoding.net](https://github.com/chadly/Geocoding.net) to reverse geocode my latitude and longitude to a formatted address.
I want a address from MapQuest and not from other providers like Yahoo, google and bing.
This is my Code:

```
    try
    {
        IGeocoder geocoder = new MapQuestGeocoder("Fmjtd%7Cluu82q6***********");
        var addresses = geocoder.ReverseGeocode(latitude, longitude);
        return ("Formatted address :  " + addresses.First().FormattedAddress);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return exception.Message;
    }
```

This code catches an exception and thorws this error "This key is not authorized for this service."

I know that this error occurs when I try to hit the Enterprise API of Geocoder i.e http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/reverse?key=*******************

For free and open source usage, I should hit this API:

http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=YOUR-KEY-HERE

How can I do this? Is there any option of passing the POST URL in the constructor itself? Or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanning over the open-source code of Geocoding.net, it looks like you just need to set the "UseOSM" property of your geocoder object to true:

```
geocoder.UseOSM = true;
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. You are right.!! Can Also be done via 
    IGeocoder geocoder = new MapQuestGeocoder("Fmjtd%7Cluu82q6***********"){UseOSM = true};

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. You dont need to chnage the URL. Simply add UseOSM=true like this:

```
try
{
    IGeocoder geocoder = new MapQuestGeocoder("Fmjtd%7Cluu82q6***********"){UseOSM = true};
    var addresses = geocoder.ReverseGeocode(latitude, longitude);
    return ("Formatted address :  " + addresses.First().FormattedAddress);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    return exception.Message;
}
```